# xampp puts some files to root folder during installing

Tags: windows-7, xampp

xampp puts some files to root folder during installing.
After installing XAMPP (xampp-win32-1.8.3-3-VC11-installer.exe, WIN7)
it puts some files : [vcredist.bmp, VC_RED.cab, install.res.1028.dll, install.exe ???] to root folder.
 I type the target install folder for XAMPP : "D:/xampp"

Can I just delete these files?

Comment: After clicking on install.exe, Ms Visual C++ 2008 Redistutable Setup wizzard appears

Comment: I don't see MS Visual C++ wizard appears (I use Windows 8.1, XAMPP 1.8.3, every previous version I also didn't see)

Answer (score 0):

These files are unnecessary and can be safely deleted from the system. The functioning of the runtime library will not be affected by this. This is a problem with a VCRedist for the RTM version of VS 2008.

If you want to read more about the bug then read this article :

[What Is install.res.1028.dll And Its Solution](https://www.techmuzz.com/how-to/windows/what-is-install-res-1028-dll-and-its-solution/)